# How to trace redirects in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, firefox-addon

I'd like an ability to trace and debug all kinds of redirects (server, javascript, html).

What is the easiest way to tell firefox to break on redirects and to display redirect information, after which I must have the ability to resume redirect?

I've tried NoRedirect, and I can't seem get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

TamperData addon for firefox.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Try "persist" button in firebugs net tab. It will keep trace of all redirects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox (with Firebug enabled), you can temporarily add these lines in a **script** element in the head of your HTML in order to trace window.location calls:

```
window.watch("location", function(id, oldv, newv) { debugger; return newv; });
document.watch("location", function(id, oldv, newv) { debugger; return newv; });
```

I think you can also extend this for **top** and **self**, but this is only useful if you're using frames. I know it's not much, but it's better than nothing and certainly much better than all the other solutions listed here. I'm still looking for a way to trace other types of JS redirects, such as window.navigate.

Answer (score -4):

You can try to install firebug plugin, and have a look on some tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: I'm already using firebug, and at this moment in time, I've got no idea about how to trace redirects with it, especially if they lead through multiple domains